# Bootstrap reduce font size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use some of the Bootstrap's components (dropdown button). So I implemented dropdown css and js files and change `html{font-size:62.5%}` to `100%` both in .css and .min.css files, but this change does not applied. When I wanted to overwrite it with my own css file, it also does not applied. How can I make the font size 100%, or disable bootstrap typography and only use some of components?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: You can go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and set the font size you want in the components you want. Then, download and update the references to your project. Make sure you don't mix versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend you not to make any changes directly in bootstrap.min.css. create a custom css file , make your changes in that file  and link it **after** bootstrap.min.css in your index.html header. in the way the changes in your custom css files will overwrite the css in bootstrap.min.css

```
    <head>
        <!--- CSS files -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    </head>
```

Now make your changes in `style.css`  :)

Comment: Adding an example would help this answer :)

Comment: Thank you ;), I don't know, why it didn't work last time. When I linked my css file after bootstrap now, it works.

Comment: Very happy to hear that your issue is fixed ..Cheers :)